What are the Windows and Linux commands to show column headers (Protocol, Local IP, Foreign IP, State, Process Name, PID, Path) for pattern searches?
I used commands like:

Windows Powershell > netstat -ano | findstr ":22"
Linux Bash Terminal > ss -tuln -p | head -n 1 && ss -tuln -p | grep ":22"

I want a simple one-line command (not complex multi-line command) for each OS to show column headers (Protocol, Local IP, Foreign IP, State, Process Name, PID, Path) for specific pattern searches.

On Linux you can use ss with -p (show process), -H (omit headers), and a search pattern for port 22:
echo "Proto Local Address Foreign Address State Process"; ss -tulnp | grep ":22".

(1) The Linux command you posted is a one-line command. Does it do what you want? Is its complicated from the only problem with it? To call it by a simple name (e.g. ssg ":22"), you need to build a script or a shell function that uses the command in the right way. Is such ssg what you want to achieve? (2) You're asking for "Windows and Linux commands". A fellow user who can answer for one OS does not necessarily can do it for the other. If two partial answers appear, each perfect for one OS, which one will you accept? Consider asking separately.
